# Access newly created DOM elements for looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery sortable + jQuery draggable to put together a page that adds and removes images to a slideshow. I have it set up now such that I can drag in new screens and drop them into the named sequences I want, and it'll create the DOM elements I need.

I am successfully scanning the page for the necessary elements and committing them to an array, but it never picks up the newly added items. So for example, I have the following elements to begin with:

```
<h3 data-sequence-title="sequence1">Sequence 1</h3>
<ul class="sortable connectedSortable ui-sortable">
    <li data-screen="screen1">Screen 1</li>
    <li data-screen="screen2">Screen 2</li>
    <li data-screen="screen3">Screen 3</li>
</ul>
```

...and I then add a row:

```
<h3 data-sequence-title="sequence1">Sequence 1</h3>
<ul class="sortable connectedSortable ui-sortable">
    <li data-screen="screen1">Screen 1</li>
    <li data-screen="screen2">Screen 2</li>
    <li data-screen="screen3">Screen 3</li>
    <li data-screen="screen4">Screen 4</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery will only ever return the first elements, not the updated ones. Here's the js I'm using:

```
$( document.body ).on('click', '.submit', function(){

    // Build nested array from DOM elements
    var jsonObj = [];    

    $('.sortable').prev('h3').each(function(){
        var obj = {
            title: $(this).data("sequence-title"),
            Screens: []
        };

        $(this).next("ul").children('li').each(function() {
          obj.Screens.push({
              image: $(this).data("screen")
          });
        });

        jsonObj.push(obj);
    });

});
```

Code that adds new LIs:

```
// Initialize draggable / droppable functionality
$('.sortable').sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    revert: true
});
$('.draggable li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.sortable',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

I need to return the modified DOM, not the elements that were there when I loaded the page.

Comment: Your markup is invalid, you can't have an `<h3>` as a direct child of a `<ul>`.

Comment: True, but not the issue here.

Comment: Can you give us the code that generates the new UL elements?

Comment: Sure, updated the original. Also moved the H3s outside the ULs.

Comment: @Adam Nelson Based on your code I made a quick example. The code allows dragging elements from a separate section into a new section. Clicking the button, shows the JSON is updated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick experiment based on your code. I am able to drag elements from below and add them to the first sequence. Then they are accessible when the clicky button is clicked.

```
  <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="moo">clicky</div>

<ul class="sortable connectedSortable ui-sortable">
    <h3 data-sequence-title="sequence1">Sequence 1</h3>
    <li data-screen="s1screen1">Seq 1 Screen 1</li>
    <li data-screen="s1screen2">Seq 1 Screen 2</li>
    <li data-screen="s1screen3">Seq 1 Screen 3</li>
</ul>



<ul class="draggable">
    <h3 data-sequence-title="sequence2">Dragable Sequence (Drag these elements up and assign to sequence 1)</h3>
    <li data-screen="s2screen1">Seq 2 Screen 1</li>
    <li data-screen="s2screen2">Seq 2 Screen 2</li>
    <li data-screen="s2screen3">Seq 2 Screen 3</li>
</ul>


<script>
$(document.getElementById('moo')).on('click', function(){

    // Build nested array from DOM elements
    var jsonObj = [];    

    $('.sortable h3').each(function(){
        var obj = {
            title: $(this).data("sequence-title"),
            Screens: []
        };

        $(this).siblings("li").each(function() {
          obj.Screens.push({
              image: $(this).data("screen")
          });
        });

        jsonObj.push(obj);
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});

// Initialize draggable / droppable functionality
$('.sortable').sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    revert: true
});
$('.draggable li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.sortable',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add an element to your sortable you have to update the component:

```
$(".sortable").sortable("refresh");
```